# is there a pythonic way to convert an input list of integer(which would be a char) into a list of integer?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to take a single line of intergers and using a for loop to convert the elements into integers, Is there a more pyhtonic way of doing so??

```
a = input().strip().split()
l = []
for i in a:
    l.append(int(i))
```

Comment: if you don't mind using NumPy, you can use `l = np.array(input().strip().split(), dtype=int)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `map` directly on `split`:

```
l = list(map(int, input().strip().split()))
```